# Blinking and fading element while ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to fade an DOM element (an SVG node) as long as calling a backend service. My frist naive implementation looks like that (but it doesn't work):

```
    $( function() {
        request = true
        $.ajax({
            url: "/mybackend"
        }).done(function() {
            request = false
            $( "#myelement" ).attr('fill', '#00FF00');
        });
        while (request) {
            $("#myelement").fadeTo('slow', 0.2).fadeTo('slow', 1.0);
        }

    } );
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with the third parameter of fadeTo, a complete function:

```
$( function() {
        var requestReturned = false;
        var fadeAndBlink = function() {
            $("#myelement").fadeTo('slow', 0.2).fadeTo('slow', 1.0, function() {
                if (requestReturned == false) {
                    fadeAndBlink();
                } else {
                    $( "#myelement" ).attr('fill', '#00FF00');
                }
            });
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: "/mybackend",
            beforeSend: fadeAndBlink
        }).done(function() {
            requestReturned = true
        });
    } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it this way:

```js
$( function() {
        // start the fade here
        $("#myelement").fadeTo('slow', 0.2).fadeTo('slow', 1.0);

        request = true

        $.ajax({
            url: "/mybackend"
        }).done(function() {
            request = false
            $( "#myelement" ).attr('fill', '#00FF00');
        });
    } );
```

Comment: Sorry, I was not precise enough: with the loop I need a blinking together with the fade until the response returns

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make and recursive function for the fade effect like this:

```
function makeFade() {
     if($("#myelement").getAttribute("fill") != '#00FF00')
     {
     $("#myelement").fadeTo('slow', 0.2).fadeTo('slow', 1.0);
     setInterval(makeFade(), 2000);
     }
}
```

Adding the call fo that function to your ajax call like this:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "/mybackend",
            beforeSend: makeFade()
        }).done(function() {                
            $( "#myelement" ).attr('fill', '#00FF00');
        });
```

I think this would work for you.
Let me know if it does.
Regards.

Comment: The blinking does look so nice. Changing the color, it's still blinking

Comment: Well can you see whats is the value of  `$("#myelement").getAttribute("fill")` ? maybe we should use a different flag like `var isBlinking = true` and use it to evalute at `makeFade()` until the callback of the AJAX changing value to `isBlinking = false`. Let me know if you keep with the same issue.

Comment: If it keep blinking after that, we should try to stop the animation after the callback. Use this `$("#myelement").stop(true,true).fadeOut();` after or before set the color.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think the best solution is with the complete function of fadeTo.